# Cant edit my code, Android Studio searches for files

Tags: android, android-studio

When i developing my app and press alt + tab or click outside from Android Studio, to search something, and clicking again in the Android Studio window, i cant edit my code anymore.

There's no cursor, when i typing words or something it searches everytime for file in my project. 
On top of my project files explorer is a grey small Window, where is the following text: 
Search for: (and the text i type)

I dont know what i have to do, to get rid of this mode.
When i restart Android Studio i can edit my code again. 
But some 20 minutes later, after clicking outside from studio, the problem comes back.

Any ideas to deactivate this "search for" mode or switching the focus on my code?

Comment: This is a somewhat known bug. Try pressing Esc and then the Windows button (between Ctrl and Alt) twice

Comment: tried, but didnt work